# SQL: Tips on structuring table to fit 3d data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-normalization

I would just like some guidance on database optimization. I have what is essentially a daily survey with a couple sliders (so float 0-1). Each day, X amount of people from the same company will fill this out, submitting their values for this "survey".

What I understand is that you should not create tables for each user as is it inefficient and unmanageable. So, I should not create a table for each company.

What I am looking for is guidance on putting all this data into one table.  Here are some specific questions:

- If each company has a 5-digit ID, and I were to record all data in the same table with a column showing id and a column with a timestamp, **how efficient would it be getting all data points from a certain company (aka 5 digit ID) when the data gets into the millions or tens of millions?**
- How much does the size of a *table* affect the efficiency when accessing?
- If I were to use a method with the 5-digit ID, would you recommend that I also assign every single "survey entry" (aka row) with its own index, per se?
- Do you have any general tips or ideas for structuring a single table with my particular case?

Thanks.

Comment: I find your question too broad to answer.  But, regarding the size of the table, a few million rows is not so large that proper indexing and tuning cannot leave it very usable for you.

Comment: Maybe it could be seen as broad, but there are two pretty specific questions.  Regardless, thank you. That's reassuring.

Comment: I think this question should be better on dba.stackexchqange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not advisable to use a single table for all your data.

I think you  could model it with few tables (schem, a in Relational notation):

```
Users(ID,name, bla, bla, bla) --user's data
Company(ID, Name, bla, bla) --company's data

question(ID,question) --a single question
survey(ID, date, some general stuff about that survey) --track each survey    
answer(ID, question_id, survey_id, user_id, company_id, answer_value) --an answer to a question (in a survey)
```

NOTE: foreign keys are indicated as *referenced_table*_ID

With this schema you can:

- give same survey to multiple companies,
- have a single user taking same survey with different values from different companies
- track each individual question
- track each individual answer
- question do not have data replication  of course, once done, you can
- of course you can write a view to have all in a single table